# How can I get more precise log sources from my Deis apps/containers?

Tags: deis

I have a [Deis](http://deis.io/) cluster running in a (hopefully-soon-to-be) Production environment, with quite a few different apps using the [Dockerfile](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/using_deis/deploy-application/#dockerfiles) deployment method. Everything's running fine, but promoting this system to a true Production environment (that is, converting the DNS over) isn't really possible unless I can get some worthwhile log output.  Using the standard [Deis logging platform](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/managing_deis/platform_logging/), here's some sample output of a Web hit (with a bit more output, for context):

```
Feb 10 01:46:04 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting Generate /run/coreos/motd...
Feb 10 01:46:04 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started Generate /run/coreos/motd.
Feb 10 01:46:08 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [info] GET /containers/json
Feb 10 01:46:08 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [215084df] +job containers()
Feb 10 01:46:08 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [215084df] -job containers() = OK (0)
Feb 10 01:46:09 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[1316]: 2015/02/10 01:46:09 set /deis/services/production-web/production-web_v8.cmd.1 -> 10.21.2.154:49409
Feb 10 01:46:12 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[9844]: 2015-02-10 01:46:12.302721 7f213ae14700  0 mon.ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal@4(peon).data_health(58) update_stats avail 80% total 102400 MB, used 17621 MB, avail 82542 MB
Feb 10 01:46:18 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [info] GET /containers/json
Feb 10 01:46:18 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [215084df] +job containers()
Feb 10 01:46:18 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal docker[1867]: [215084df] -job containers() = OK (0)
Feb 10 01:46:19 ip-10-23-1-151.ec2.internal sh[1521]: [INFO] - [10/Feb/2015:01:46:27 +0000] - 10.21.2.179 - - - 200 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" - 4927 - "-" - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36" - "~^production-web\x5C.(?<domain>.+)$" - 10.21.2.154:49409
Feb 10 01:46:19 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[8468]: ===========
Feb 10 01:46:19 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[8468]: HIT TRACKER
Feb 10 01:46:19 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[8468]: SLUG: public/javascripts/bundle.js
Feb 10 01:46:19 ip-10-21-2-154.ec2.internal sh[8468]: ===========
```

That contains *alot* of platform information – which is great to have, if only I could filter it out. The problem is all the lines for which the source is `sh`, but with different PIDs.  Those are each completely different containers:

- `1316` is deis-publisher
- `9844` is deis-store-monitor
- `1521` is deis-router
- `8468` is my web application, production-web

The only way for me to find that out is to ssh into the box and run `ps`.  What's worse, if I had any logs from my other containers at the same time, they would have *also* shown up as `sh` – in a production environment with several active apps all logging to the same stream, this situation is obviously untenable. The ideal situation would have `sh` replaced by the name of the Docker container or, preferably, the Deis app.

I've poured over the documentation and dug into the [logspout](https://github.com/deis/logspout) and [logger](https://github.com/deis/deis/tree/master/logger) source code, but I can't find anything to fix this. Any chance I could get some pointers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get at the name of the deis container that logged the line, the best way I've found is either:

1. To run the output of `journalctl -f -o short` through netcat to a fluentd or logstash tcp listener. You can use these tools to summarize the fields like `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` that appeal to your needs.
2. Use [ianblenke/fluentd](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ianblenke/fluentd/) with `LOG_DOCKER_JSON` defined or fork and modify the autobuild source [docker-ianblenke/fluentd](https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-fluentd). This uses the [fluentd-docker](http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging) plugin to follow the raw docker container json logs.

If you're using CoreOS, I use this [fluentd.cloud-init](https://github.com/ianblenke/coreos-vagrant-kitchen-sink/blob/master/tested/fluentd.cloud-init) to auto-feed my logs to a local elasticsearch instance on TCP 9200. Will fill find other useful CoreOS cloud-init configs in that project as well.

Comment: Thanks, IanBlenke, this may very well work for us. But I'm super disappointed that Deis doesn't have a solution for effective app-specific logging! I wonder how other production apps deal with this issue.